# Is there a way to use OpenID for identification (not just authentication)?

Tags: openid, openid-provider, cardspace, infocard

Is there a way to perform **identification** with OpenID, not just **authentication**?

With OpenID i give an OpenID-enabled web-site my *identifier*, e.g.:

[image]

And then the *relying party* asks the OpenID provider if i do, in fact, own the identifier "*ianboyd.stackoverflow.com*".

But this isn't what i want. i want what Google and Facebook do; which violates the OpenID standard.

A "Google OpenID" enabled site transfers to google. From there i perform a login (identification and authentication), and an **identifcation** is returned to the *relying party*.

That's what i want. But i want to use OpenID, so i don't have to ask every site on the internet to support my custom security implementation. In other words:

Is there a way to perform ***identification*** with OpenID, not just **authentication**?

---

The reason i want this is that my OpenID provider use Windows Cardspace for *identification* and *authentication*. The provider will pop up Windows Cardspace on a secure desktop:

[image]

From **there** i can choose an existing identity, or choose to create a new one. The identity has a unique, private, identification number, that can be returned to the relying party.

But without a way to return an *identity*, then i cannot use OpenID for *identification*.

Comment: I am confused. Openid authenticates *identities*, and identities is represented as OpenID URL. What does Google do that other OpenID idPs *don't* do?

Comment: Google's OpenID url is not my unique identity (`https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id`) which i then prove that i own. In canonical OpenID, i present a string that identify's me (e.g. `ianboyd.myopenid.net`), which i then prove i own.

Answer (score 0):

Most client implementations do just that. I used a Python implementaion for OpenID and it offered me two ways to authenticate; one of them was redirection, where actually log in on the OpenID site before getting re-directed back to the original site.

Also, you use the OpenID URL to associate account/user data with it.

Take a look at how StackOverflow does it. ;)

Also read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID

Comment: **My** OpenID url (`https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id`) is an id that is shared with a lot of people. What i cannot find in OpenID is the mechanism where my **identity** can be returned to the caller.

Comment: What do you understand under the term *identity*?

Comment: And my OpenID url is `http://timothy.green.name` which merely has a few meta tags.